# how to get RGB numbers from a list

Tags: python, list, rgb

I used colorgram library, and got a list of RGB color code.

```
[<colorgram.py Color: Rgb(r=80, g=97, b=85), 42.86094708532268%>,
 <colorgram.py Color: Rgb(r=34, g=48, b=37), 20.90975231208169%>,
 <colorgram.py Color: Rgb(r=29, g=26, b=18), 12.300570275661888%>]
```

I want to extract the numbers of RGB numbers like this.

```
[[80, 97, 85], [34, 48, 37], [29, 26, 18]]
```

but each element's type is 'colorgram.cologram.Color', and the length of list is variable. how can I get RGB numbers?

Comment: If you `print(colorgram.color.Color.__dict__)` what's in there? You should get a list of `Color()` class attributes...maybe one of them is the RGB list?

Comment: Complete guess that it is `[[x.rgb.r, x.rgb.g, x.rgb.b] for x in l]`

Comment: @TomMcLean Good guess. But since x.rgb is also an iterable, you can also just say list(x.rgb)

Comment: @chrslg That was my second guess but you posted an answer before I could edit, so I just left it ;)

Comment: [The official example](https://github.com/obskyr/colorgram.py#example) seems to be pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

```py
[list(c.rgb) for c in l]
```

where l is your list of colorgram should do

Example

```py
import colorgram
l=colorgram.extract("file.png", 6)
colors=[list(c.rgb) for c in l]
```

`[f(x) for x in iterable]` is the compound list syntax. So it's a way to compute a list a f(x) from a list of x.
Here, what I do is taking each colorgram c in l, and computing list(c.rgb) from it.

c begin a colorgram, c.rgb is the rgb color or that colorgram (but still in the form of a type specific of the colorgram package. That allows to also access by fields [c.r, c.g, c.b]).
And list(c.rgb) transforms this rgb color in a list of 3 int.

Answer (score 0):

The rgb values are stored as a named tuple that is stored under the `.rgb` property of the `Color` object.

You can extract an rgb triple by just calling `my_color.rgb`.

If you want to make a list of lists of rgb values then, and have all of your `Colors` objects stored in a list that is named `my_colors` you can use:

```py
rgb_list = [list(color.rgb) for color in my_colors]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import colorgram as cg


ab=cg.extract("image.jpg", 3000000)
color_palette = []

for count in ab:
    r = count.rgb.r
    g = count.rgb.g
    b = count.rgb.b
    new_tuple=(r,g,b)

    color_palette.append(new_tuple)

print(color_palette)



try this it will work....
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).